# How to get task_id in group by

Tags: postgresql

I have a table task_activity

```
create table task_activity(
  id serial,
  task_date timestamp,
  task_id int
);
```

which has data regarding tasks completed

```
(1, '2020-01-30 01:00:00',1)
(2, '2020-01-29 01:00:00',1)

(3, '2020-01-15 01:00:00',1)
(4, '2020-01-14 01:00:00',1)
(5, '2020-01-13 01:00:00',1)

(6, '2020-01-30 01:00:00',2)
(7, '2020-01-16 01:00:00',2)

(8, '2020-01-15 01:00:00',2)
(9, '2020-01-14 01:00:00',2)
(10, '2020-01-13 01:00:00',2)
```

I run the following query

```
WITH
  groups(date, dateMinusRow) AS (
    SELECT
      date_trunc('day', task_date) date,
      date_trunc('day', task_date) - INTERVAL '1' DAY * DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY date_trunc('day', task_date)) dateMinusRow
    FROM task_activity
    GROUP BY date_trunc('day', task_date)
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= 1
  )
SELECT
  COUNT(*) AS streak,
  MIN(date) AS startDate,
  MAX(date) AS endDate
FROM groups
GROUP BY dateMinusRow
ORDER BY endDate DESC
```

to get this data

```
streak  startdate   enddate
2   2020-01-29T00:00:00Z    2020-01-30T00:00:00Z
4   2020-01-13T00:00:00Z    2020-01-16T00:00:00Z
```

How do I include the column task_id in this data too?

Comment: @Larnu my apologies, changed tags now, yes I am not using sql, I am using postgres.

Comment: As far as I can tell including task_id would change your query fundamentally, you can group by "date", or by "task_id", or by "date and task_id". But you cannot group by date and then expect task_id's too.

Comment: For each `dateMinusRow` associated with more than one `task_id`, which `task_id` did you want in the result?  What logic explains your choice?